# Adding a path with spaces doesn't work in OSX El Capitan

Tags: macos, path, osx-elcapitan, spaces

I tried adding a path to my .bash_profile that has a space in it (/Applications/Racket\ v6.12/bin) and after doing so it appears in my PATH variable as expected but does not give me access to the path. I've done the usual 'close all terminal windows', 'log out and back in', etc. and no matter what, the added path doesn't work (I can't run any binaries from that path in my terminal without specifying the full path in front of it).

I even tried adding it to /etc/paths instead of my .bash_profile to make it system-wide (after removing it from my .bash_profile first of course). This shouldn't even be necessary because the path appears in my PATH variable when using .bash_profile but I thought I would try it anyway.

I even did this to try to escape the double quotes:

```
export PATH="\"/Applications/Racket\ v6.12/bin\":$PATH"
```

and various combinations of the above (without the escaped space, etc.)

The only solution I found was to create a symbolic link without spaces. For example, I did this:

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/Racket\ v6.12/ /usr/local/racket
```

and then I added /usr/local/racket/bin to my path (works using either .bash_profile or /etc/paths).

```
export PATH="/usr/local/racket/bin:$PATH"
```

This worked but I can't believe that users have to resort to creating symbolic links to get their paths with spaces to work. Am I missing something here? Is there a more idiomatic way to add a path with spaces in it? I'm using OSX El Capitan 10.11.6.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, answered my own question, so posting it here for anyone else having a similar issue. I tried this after seeing another example:
`export PATH="/Applications/Racket v6.12/bin":$PATH`
and it worked. The key is the double quotes around the path with spaces ONLY, not around the entire variable string as I mistakenly did.